# How to translate this to jQuery - "if siblings does not contain element with class = "foo" do something..."

Tags: jquery

How to translate this to jQuery - 
"if siblings does not contain element with class = "foo" do something..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost like how you say it:

```
if ($(element).siblings('.foo').length == 0) {
}
```

*If element's siblings with class 'foo' do not exist, do ...*

See also: [`siblings(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Just as I would have done it. On a related note, I love jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 var siblingssWithoutFooClass = $('#elementId').siblings().not('.foo');
```